# Convert timedelta value to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, timedelta, odoo-12

I need to save a `timedelta` value into a float type fields.

Here is my code:

```
if self.end_time and self.start_time:
        timediff =self.end_time - self.start_time // Here i get a time.delta value
        self.duration = // here i get an error
```

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
'datetime.timedelta'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The code above is not valid Python: `//` is not a comment marker in Python, and your `self.duration =` assignment is missing exactly the code fragment which is causing your problem. Please paste something that actually exhibits the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is incomplete, but assuming you're actually doing something like this:

```
self.duration = float(timediff)
```

… and what you want is the total number of seconds represented by `timediff` as a float, you can get that using the [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method:

```
self.duration = timediff.total_seconds()
```

This returns a float, so no conversion is necessary.